# How Can I Unzip A Folder Using Java(netbeans)?

Tags: java, api, netbeans, zip

Hey Guys I am New To Stack Overflow As well As programming. I am Working On A project Which Require me to unzip a zipped folder. I looked for some solution online but none of them work. So if anybody know how to unzip a folder Even With Some API, Please Tell. Every Help Is Appreciated.

BTW I am Using **NetBeans 7.3.1** and **jdk1.8.0_261**

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: [Read this Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress).

Comment: If you're asking how to unzip a zipfile in Java code, do a web search for `ZipInputStream` -- there are lots of examples. The IDE tool you're using shouldn't make any difference to how you do this (unless I've completely misunderstood the question).

Comment: Does Anyone Know how to use zip4j to extract a zip?